# Create mysql database using cpanel api

Tags: php, api, cpanel, whm

I am trying to create mysql database using cpanel xmlapi.
After search on google i found the below code.

```
$auth_user = 'XXXXXX'; 
$auth_pass = 'XXXXX'; 
$server = 'XXXXXXXX.com';
$json_client = new \xmlapi($server);
$json_client->set_output('json'); 
$json_client->set_port(2083); 
$json_client->password_auth($auth_user, $auth_pass);
$json_client->set_debug(1);
# Create Database
$result = $json_client->api1_query($auth_user, 'Mysql', 'adddb',array($shop->alias));
var_dump($result);
```

After running this code I got this error:

```
string(202) "{"cpanelresult":{"apiversion":"2","error":"The â€œcpanel_jsonapi_moduleâ€ parameter is required.","data":{"reason":"The â€œcpanel_jsonapi_moduleâ€ parameter is required.","result":"0"},"type":"text"}}"
```

Comment: I can't find any documentation, do you have a link to the cpanel API docs?

Comment: The api is in this link .https://snipt.net/paptamas/xmlapiphp/

Comment: Are you sure the `Mysql` module and the `adddb` function exist?

Comment: addb is file name of the cpanel : https://host:2082/frontend/x/sql/adddb.html

Comment: if you know  any other way to do this  let me know.

Comment: I don't know any other way but I'm not sure you can do this using this particular API. You should try posting in the cPanel forums and opening a support ticket with them.

Comment: Means there is no other way to create database programmatically ?

Comment: Not as far as I know, which doesn't mean much since I am by no means an expert on cPanel manipulation through PHP.